# Python fastest way of moving Web table data to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

Running a selenium code to get the data from a retailer site to get titles and prices. I use a loop to assign values from find_elements, however it seems to move rather slow. Is there a faster way to assign all text values to pandas DF?

```
browser.get("https://www.hipercor.es/supermercado/buscar/?term=la+casera&search=text")
time.sleep(1)
titles = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='product_tile-description']")
prices = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='prices product_tile-prices']")
            for i in range(len(titles)):
                our_list = {"PRICE": prices[i].text, "PRODUCT": titles[i].text}
                df_dict = pd.DataFrame([our_list])
                hiper = pd.concat([hiper, df_dict], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: What part is slow?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
io = f'https://www.hipercor.es/supermercado/buscar/?term=la+casera&search=text'
df = pd.read_html(io,)
```

Documentation [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

Comment: The table is not in a typical format i.e. li, td etc. so the line read_html breaks i.e. gets stuck.

Comment: @Vaidas, I don't think I can answer your question when I can not see the html format. Maybe you can copy the HTML then add it you your question. That way we can see if it is created by <li>,<div> or something else.